# latest 1.1.5 ng-animate not working with ng-show

Tags: angularjs

The following code is adopted from a working sample for angular 1.1.4, only using the new GreenSock api for ng-animate.  toggle functionality works, as ng-show behaves as expected, however The AppAnimation functions 'list-in' and 'list-out' are not being called on ng-show.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <style>
    .box { color: white; text-align: center; height: 100px; font-size: 86px; }
    .on  { background-color: green; }
    .off { background-color: red; }
  </style>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.9.7/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
  <script>
      angular.module('AppAnimations', [])
      .animation('list-out', ['$window',function($window) {
        return {
          start : function(element, done) {
            console.log('list-out')
            TweenMax.set(element, {position:'relative'});

            var duration = 1; 
            //we can use onComplete:done with TweenMax, but lets use
            //a delay value for testing purposes
            TweenMax.to(element, 1, {opacity:0, width:0});
            $window.setTimeout(done, duration * 1000);
          }
        }
      }])

      .animation('list-in', ['$window',function($window) {
        return {
          setup: function(element) {
            TweenMax.set(element, {opacity:0, width:0});
          },
          start : function(element, done) {
            console.log('list-in')
            var duration = 1; 
            //we can use onComplete:done with TweenMax, but lets use
            //a delay value for testing purposes
            TweenMax.to(element, duration, {opacity:1, width:210});
            $window.setTimeout(done, duration * 1000);
          }
        }
      }])

      angular.module('myApp', ['AppAnimations'])
        .controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
          $scope.toggle = true;
        }])
  </script>

    </head>
   <body  ng-app="myApp"  ng-controller="MainController">
     <button ng-click="toggle = !toggle">Toggle!</button>

      <div class="box on" ng-show="toggle" ng-animate="{leave:'list-out', enter:'list-in'}">On</div>
      <div class="box off" ng-hide="toggle" ng-animate="{leave:'list-out', enter:'list-in'}">Off</div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="box on" ng-show="toggle" ng-animate="{show: 'list-in', hide: 'list-out'}">On</div>
<div class="box off" ng-hide="toggle" ng-animate="{show: 'list-in', hide: 'list-out'}">Off</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I finally solved it.. you are using `leave/enter` and should be using `show/hide`.  I updated the names to be more PC correct.

```
<div class="box on" ng-show="toggle" ng-animate="{hide:'list-hide', show:'list-show'}">On</div>
<div class="box off" ng-hide="toggle" ng-animate="{hide:'list-hide', show:'list-show'}">Off</div>
```

---

```
angular.module('AppAnimations', [])
  .animation('list-hide', ['$window',function($window) {
 ...
 ).animation('list-show', ['$window',function($window) {
```

Working fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/ncapito/CTfL8/

Comment: gave moderndegree the accept. beat you by three minutes. didn't do the fiddle, and crossed the finish line first :)

Comment: in all fairness, I believe he answered first. I think his edit came after though.

Comment: @musictray he did not beat me, i beat him by 3 minutes.  I edited, had the correct and and just cleaned some things up. So lame.